# What defines a "Top Tag"?

Tags: support, tags, badges, generalist-badge

For the Generalist badge, the requirements are: `Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags`

What defines what these 40 top tags are?

I assume it is just the tags listed under `Tags -> Popular`, but I wasn't sure about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly what it says on the tin: the 40 top tags are the 40 first elements in the [tag list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags). That list is ordered by the number of questions decorated with each tag, descending.

Also note that the `Generalist` badge won't be available until all of the 40 top tags decorate 200 questions or more.